# How to change image size based on the resolution?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a image that will enlarge or shrink based on screen resolution.

I am using bootstrap and want to change the image size. The problem is the image is not that big and I am not sure how to enlarge the image if the user expend the browser window.

My html is like:

```
<div>
 <img class='col-md-12' src='img.png'/>
</div>
```

css

```
img{
  width:100%;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Isn't your css doing the trick, when you specify the width in percentage?

Answer (score 2):

**this will help you- these are the jQuery libraries for resize images on responsive view**

http://responsiveimg.com/

http://responsejs.com/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
 <img class='col-md-12' src='test.jpg'/>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div{
    width: 100%;
}
img{
    min-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Here is a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hsD2G/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap provide `css` for the images in responsive site. only you have to give class `img-responsive` to make image resizable. see Responsive images in http://getbootstrap.com/css

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Bootstrap 3.0 give the image a class of "img-responsive" cause bootstrap already has a responsive image class setup like so:

```
.img-responsive {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

So for you I would use:

```
<div>
    <img class="img-responsive" src='img.png'/>
</div>
```